# How Can I fix "Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects" error

Tags: python, variables, pulp

Currently I have an LP model and while I'm trying to run it, the constraint

```
for i in DEMANDPOINT:
    prob += (lpSum(z[i][j]) == 1 for j in FACILITY5)
```

causes this error to pop up.

TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What variable are you trying to sum over?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because are adding to your problem a generator of constraints, where each constraint is of the form `z[i][j] == 1`, which is probably not what you want.

In case you are trying to add a constraint on the z variables with the sum over all the values of `j` for a given `i` must be one, then you can write it as follows.

```
for i in DEMANDPOINT:
    prob += lpSum(z[i][j] for j in FACILITY5) == 1
```